# SCORM and JavaScript: How to make a web application SCORM compatible?

Tags: javascript, scorm, scorm2004

I have a web application that plays an HTML5 video. I would like to know how to make this application SCORM compatible.

I am not looking for a program to produce and export SCORM content, but I would like to know how to create a SCORM package from scratch.

Via pipwerks I already found a javascript API library, which describes this approach very general: https://pipwerks.com/2008/05/08/adding-scorm-code-to-an-html-file/

Pipwerks is great, but I would like to know which functions from the library need to be called in the different cases of one SCORM course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally that is going to depend on what data you want captured in the SCORM information model. IOW, does watching some portion of the video equate to a concept of "completion"? Or does it mean something like "pass"? Maybe the amount of video watched is a score value? You could go so far as to capture individual moments such as pause, play, skip, etc. via the interactions model. Essentially you need to decide what it is that you want to record, that then can be translated into the SCORM calls that are necessary, and then how to produce those results given your chosen library. For much more detail I would suggest reading through https://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/, particularly starting from "Using the API". Minimally you'll want to make sure `Initialize` and `Terminate` are called. Also be sure to test your content in Rustici's SCORM Cloud https://cloud.scorm.com (it is free for this purpose).

Comment: My web application plays the video and interrupts some places and then shows a task within the videos. Accordingly, a user must view the video to complete the course and solve various tasks to pass the course. For this I need then the corresponding API calls. Thanks for your hints :)

Comment: Glad it helped. You've found the PipWerks wrapper, if you need to support multiple learning standards (and versions of SCORM) through one interface you may also want to consider using Rustici's Driver (shameless plug): https://rusticisoftware.com/products/rustici-driver/